# How HBase/Bigtable can be used for data analysis?

Tags: bigdata, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

Conceptually, HBase/Bigtable are key-value stores. Many times when reading the documentation of both, it is mentioned that they can be used for analytics. But since they are key-value and doesn't support SQL or SQL like language how they are used for analytics?

> Cloud Bigtable also excels as a storage engine for batch MapReduce
>   operations, stream processing/analytics, and machine-learning
>   applications. ([source](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview))

Comment: I think the key phrase here is "storage engine", and not the machine-learning engine itself.

Comment: Since when do you need SQL to perform analytics?

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytics tools such as Hadoop MapReduce, Apache Spark, and Apache Beam / Google Cloud Dataflow on HBase and Cloud Bigtable, e.g., see:

- [Dataflow connector for Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-dataflow-java)
- [Connect Apache Spark to your HBase database](https://medium.com/@contactsunny/connect-apache-spark-to-your-hbase-database-spark-hbase-connector-f61f591b75df)
- [`HBaseIO` connector for Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/hbase/HBaseIO.html)
- [`BigtableIO` connector for Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.html)

Additionally, TensorFlow is integrated with Cloud Bigtable for ML training, eg., see:

- [Using Cloud Bigtable as a streaming data source for TensorFlow](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/bigtable-resnet)
- [TensorFlow APIs for accessing data in Cloud Bigtable](https://github.com/tensorflow/io/tree/master/tensorflow_io/bigtable/#readme)

Finally, you can run SQL analytics via integrations, e.g., BigQuery can run SQL queries on data stored in Cloud Bigtable; Apache Hive can run SQL queries on data stored in Apache HBase; e.g., see:

- [BigQuery + Cloud Bigtable federated queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable)
- [Hive + HBase integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration)